# Archimedean copula parameters?

Tags: r, copula

Using R, I am attempting to fit data for 3 stock indices using 3 Archimedean copulas, Frank, Gumbel or Clayton. What are their parameters?

In class, we were taught to fit a t copula. Its parameters come from getting the correlation matrix (see last two lines of codes below).

[This](http://www.inside-r.org/node/56066), [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/copula/docs/joeCopula) and [this](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/copula/man/archmCopula.html) don't seem to help, I think. In the examples, there are some numbers plugged in to the copulas, but I don't really see how to determine the numbers to use? Help please?

---

```
library(copula)

dat=read.csv("index.csv")

hk=dat$Hangseng

jp=dat$Nikkei

cn=dat$SSE

new.dat=data.frame(hk,jp,cn)

new.ts=ts(new.dat)
plot(new.ts)
ret=diff(log(new.ts))
plot(ret)

uni=pobs(ret)

uni

uni.dat=data.frame(uni)

uni.dat

plot(uni.dat)
```

**`cor(uni.dat)`**

**`t.cop=tCopula(c(0.12,0.08,0.005), dim=3,dispstr="un",df.fixed=F)`**

Comment: When you say "what are their parameters?" what do you want to know about them? Have you looked at the vignette for the package?

Comment: @Glen_b For the the tcopula, we need the correlation matrix since the parameters for fitting a t copula require such. What do I need for Frank, Clayton and Gumbel? I've seen the examples and thus the numbers but don't understand from where the numbers come

Comment: You've basically only repeated what you already said. If I explain what I think you want, I will no doubt largely repeat information you've already read. Sometimes copulas might be estimated by ML, or by equating sample and population Kendall's tau (a method-of-moments-like estimator), or in a number of other ways. The special structure of Archimedean copulas means there's a large number of ways to estimate their parameters. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.6032.pdf) gives Kendall's $\tau$ in terms of $\theta$ for these cases, so you could back out $\hat\theta$ (see table 2), ...

Comment: ... and describes ML for them as well. Some of that information is also in the vignette I mentioned before (which is why I asked if you'd read it). The parameters all represent strength of association in some sense, but they don't necessarily correspond directly to some naturally interpretable sample quantity.

Comment: The theta's correspond directly the the parameters of the functions. For example, (if I have this right), the Clayton copula has the form $C_\theta(u,v)=\max\left([u^{-\theta}+v^{-\theta}-1]^{-1/\theta},0\right)$. Table 2 in the paper I linked to gives Kendall's tau as $\tau = \frac{\theta}{\theta+2}$. So if you used Kendall's tau to estimate $\theta$ in the Clayton, you would equate $\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\hat{\theta}+2}$ with the sample Kendall tau, $\hat{\tau}$ and solve for $\hat{\theta}$.

Comment: One reference on estimation would be: Shih, JH and Louis, TA (1995),  
"Inferences on the association parameter in copula models for bivariate survival data,"  
*Biometrics*;51(4):1384-99.

Comment: I am not sure which pages you're asking me to point you at. Note that the copula package has a number of functions related to Kendall's-tau in it.

Comment: @Glen_b So all I have to do is get Kendall's Tau and then get theta and then plug that in? Oh man. Why didn't anyone just say so? Thanks so much! I will try that out!

Comment: @Glen_b What if I have 3 parameters? How I get Kendall's Tau? Looking up now but just in case hahahaha

Comment: @Glen_b If K's Tau is really for just 2, then we're cutting 1 one out...unless you can suggest otherwise? :)

Comment: (Error fixed) To my recollection, the bivariate copulas have one parameter. When you say three parameters, I assume you mean you have three variables? Then you need to use the properties of the Archimedean generator to build up a trivariate copula. There's a number of ways to construct things that can make specification/estimation of Archimedean copulas relatively simple. [But in any case, the Kendall tau(/method-of-moments-like) approach is also one of many - if you read the things I pointed to, or even just my earlier comments, you'll have seen that already. You don't have to use that one.]

Comment: Ah; according to [this paper on using the package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v34/i09/paper), the `copula` package only offers maximum pseudo-likelihood (mpl) estimation for d>2. If you wanted anything else you'd have to do it by hand. (I was thinking about using something like vine copulas, which you build from bivariate copulas and for which you could use the Kendall approach)

Comment: Thank you so much @Glen_b . This is really appreciated and will not be put to waste.

Comment: @Glen_b Maybe I'll save that for PhD :p loljk. Yeah I'll remove one then. Just gonna go with the most correlated pair. Thank you so much Glen_b. The Kendall Tau - theta thing was all I needed

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using mpl estimation, through; I think the `copula` will happily do all the work. Or you could use the vinecopula package to build a vine copula.

Comment: @Glen_b Oh wait. I found this. I didn't understand it initially hahaha thanks again so much "fitCopula(t.cop,uni,method="itau")" and then another for irho, ml...:))

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking for the parameters, you might not have seen the table in the section "Archimedean copulas" in the wikipedia entry on [copulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) (taken from Nelsen's introductory book). There, you will find the parameter spaces for a few Archimedean copulas including Frank, Gumbel and Clayton. You will realize that they are quite different and are not easy interpretable values such as the correlation matrix used for the t or Gaussian copula families. In the first place, they are just some arbitrary parameters - nothing more. In some cases, 1-1 relationships between a copula's parameter and Kendall's tau or Spearman's rho exist allowing for a re-parameterisation into an easier interpretable parameter space.

A limitation of higher (d>2) dimensional Archimedean copulas is that they still only have a single parameter that determines all dependencies in the d-dimensional data set. Hence they lack flexibility compared to t and Gaussian copulas that would e.g. take 3 correlation values for d=3. Nevertheless, the Archimedean copulas might in some cases still provide a better fit.

When it comes to estimation, as pointed out in other replies to your question, maximum likelihood estimation is the most frequently used approach. You will find an implementation of different estimation techniques bundled in the fitCopula function of the copula package in R. Take a look at the help page (?fitCopula) and try a few of the presented examples, this should enable you to use it for your own data set.

If you managed to get single family fits for your data set but are not yet satisfied (or just curious), I recommend to take a look at vine copulas (introduced as [pair-copula construction](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167668707000194) and implemented in the [VineCopula](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VineCopula/index.html) R package). Vine copulas allow to mix arbitrary bivariate copulas following  a regular vine to build multivariate copulas.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can fit any copula by maximizing the likelihood of its density:

1. Compute empirical marginals:
   $$\hat{F}_i(x_{it})=\dfrac{\#x_i\leq x_{it}}{T},\qquad t = 1...T,\,\,i = 1...n$$
2. Copula ML: $$\max_{\theta_c\in\Theta_c} \,\, l(\theta_c)=\sum_{t = 1}^{T}\ln \, c(\theta_c|\hat{F}_1(x_{1t}),\dots,\hat{F}_n(x_{nt}))$$

$\theta_c$ is the Copula parameter set you want to estimate.

Comment: thanks but my goal is not to fit copulas by writing. I want to use R. I got the data of the stock indices...now what? For t copula all I have to do is type cor(uni.dat) and then plug in  t.cop=tCopula(c(0.12,0.08,0.005), dim=3,dispstr="un",df.fixed=F)...so what I'm wondering is, what are the "0.12,0.08,0.005" I have to plug in if I want to fit Gumbel, Frank or Clayton? Wait, I think the answer is somewhere else here. Hahaha. But yeah that's what I meant to ask. Sorry if I caused any confusion